# Row-wise non zero product in matrix notation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, notation, matlab

If I have a matrix $\mathbf{A}\in R^{m\times n}$, I'd like to express in matrix notation (or at least in a good mathematical notation) the vector $\mathbf{z}\in R^{m}$ whose $i$-th component is the product of all non zero entries in the $i$-th row of $\mathbf{A}$.

I know there are some operators in some programming languages like `prod` that makes the product of a row/column vector entries, and some procedural ways to get the nonzero elements, but I am looking for a way to formalize this in a formula, if there is a common way to do it.

Comment: supposing all entries are zero, what do you wish the answer to be?

Comment: good point. In my particular case I can assure that at least one entry shall be non zero, so I guess the answer should be `undefined`. However, more in general one I can imagine saying `0` could be fine for some contexes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is reasonable to go with 
$$
z_i = \prod_{\{j: A_{ij} \neq 0\}} A_{ij}
$$
In the event that all elements are zero, this is the [empty product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_product), which is conventionally taken to be $1$.